# .NET 6 minimal api - return interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface, .net-6.0

I have troubles to return an interface with the new minimal Api.
Lets assume the follow simple scenario:

```
interface ICar {
    public string PropA {get; set; }
}

class CarExample : ICar {
  public string PropA {get; set; }
  public string PropB {get; set; }
}

app.MapGet("/car", async ([FromServices] ICarRepository carRepository, int carId)
{
    var car = await carRepository.GetCarByIdAsync(carId);
    return car;
})
```

The carRespository returns ICar as Result.
Unfortunately the Json Result has no ProbB.
Casting is not an option, because I do not know the exact Car.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to cast `car` to `object`:

```cs
app.MapGet("/car", async ([FromServices] ICarRepository carRepository, int carId) =>
{
    ...
    return (object)car;
});
```

I pretty much sure it happens due to how `System.Text.Json` handles generics during serialization:

```cs
ICar car = ...;
var serialize = JsonSerializer.Serialize(car); // contains only ICar props
var serialize1 = JsonSerializer.Serialize<object>(car); // contains all props
```

See the [docs on polymorphic serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-polymorphism).

Comment: Casting to object works. Thank you. Is it possible to configure the serialization, so I no longer need casting?